# UITableViewAutomaticDimension not working with custom table cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

there is plenty of question answering the dynamic height for UITableViewCell of UITableView. However i can't solve my problem.

I have this table cell creation code:

```
class UINoteTabelViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.selectionStyle = .none
    }

    func fill(_ note: Note) {
        let view = UINote(withNote: note, atPoint: .zero)
        self.contentView.addSubview(view)
    }
}
```

This is how i create cell for table view:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NotePreview", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! UINoteTabelViewCell

        cell.fill(notes[indexPath.row] as! Note)
        return cell
    }
```

Also table view `estimatedRowHeight` and `rowHeight` are sets to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

But table view still draws with 44.0 rows height.

I have no idea how to fix it.

PS I can't set fixed `estimatedRowHeight` because every cell have dynamic height

Comment: `estimatedRowHeight` should not be `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. Try setting it to `100` and the `rowHeight` to UITableViewAutomaticDimension.

Comment: UITableViewAutomaticDimension works with constraints, You need to add proper constraints by which cell can calculate its height

Comment: make sure your lable number of line zero

Comment: Try writing `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automatic height works on calculated cell's `contentView` height. You therefore have to add constraints that will be used to calculate its real height.

Try this:

```
class UINoteTabelViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.selectionStyle = .none
    }

    func fill(_ note: Note) {
        let view = UINote(withNote: note, atPoint: .zero)
        self.contentView.addSubview(view)

        // this will make the difference to calculate it based on view's size:
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Also, `estimatedRowHeight` should be set to a specific value that approximately estimates the size of all cells. But that would not be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should give the **estimatedRowHeight** some *default value*, say 60.
Then the rows will have a default height of 60 but whenever the content needs height more than 60 at that time **UITableViewAutomaticDimension** will work.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are just adding NoteView on cell contentView. You should also apply auto layout constraint on your note view like leading, trailing, top and bottom. 
If you apply correct auto layout constraint on your note view, hope it will work.